# Python selenium - Error when click on Google search button

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to perform google search using selenium python, but I can't seem to click the google search button with it. I am trying with the below code

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'https://google.com'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
name = 'q'
search_el = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
search_el.send_keys("selenium python")
submit_btn_el = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']")
print(submit_btn_el.get_attribute('name'))
time.sleep(2)
submit_btn_el.click()
```

It fills the search bar with the search string selenium python correctly but an exception while clicking the button:

```
[24660:18480:0504/185929.817:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors
[24660:18480:0504/185929.881:ERROR:configuration_policy_handler_list.cc(90)] Unknown policy: EnableCommonNameFallbackForLocalAnchors

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58996/devtools/browser/7031edca-5982-4156-b093-e03f85607449
[24660:18480:0504/185929.983:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/apugazhenthy/Documents/30 days of python/Day 16/google.py", line 18, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[type='submit']"))).click()  
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in 
click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in 
execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, 
in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input class="gNO89b" value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit" data-ved="0ahUKEwjbtaqk15rpAhVExzgGHS16BW0Q4dUDCAc"> is not clickable at point (431, 521). Other element would receive the click: <div class="fbar">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
```

And this is the HTML form code from the web:

```
<input class="gNO89b" value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit" data-ved="0ahUKEwjHw5eTuprpAhXGjKQKHd7SCZkQ4dUDCAs">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RETURN key seems to be working :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://google.com')

browser.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("selenium python"+Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Its work like a charm!!. Can you help me understand that how do that return keys function made click on the search?

Comment: You have two ways of sending query string to Google: 1) click on the `Search` button; 2) type `Enter` (Return) key.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if the search button is located within a different iframe? When using Selenium, if the item you want to access is located within a different iframe, you have to switch to that iframe first, and then you can access the item. you can use `switchTo()` for that.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I did not find any iframe for the search button.

Answer (score 0):

Induce a `WebDriverWait` before clicking the button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://google.com'
browser.get(url)

name = 'q'
search_el = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
search_el.send_keys("selenium python")

WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='aajZCb']//input[@value='Google Search']"))).click()

#submit_btn_el = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']")
#print(submit_btn_el.get_attribute('name'))
```

Comment: Hi ,  Thanks for your reply, Unforutenly I am getting the same issue for your suggestion as well.    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input class="gNO89b" value="Google Search" aria-label="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit" data-ved="0ahUKEwjbtaqk15rpAhVExzgGHS16BW0Q4dUDCAc"> is not clickable at point (431, 521). Other element would receive the click: <div class="fbar">...</div>

Comment: Strange, it works at my end. Could you try copy/pasting my answer 'as-is' in a new file and run it? Can't help but think there's something else causing the issue.

Comment: I've changed the identification string to ensure uniqueness, as there is more than one element with input[type='submit'].

Comment: Thank you a lot!! it working as expected after tried with your second suggestion.:)